# Share SSL socket with child process

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm working at a server that needs to support wss://. The server needs to process the websocket header, to identify the request, and then may decide to pass the SSL context to a worker process. For now, the server uses OpenSSL for SSL comunications, but from my understanding sharing a secure socket between processes is not possible with OpenSSL (tried with SSL_SESSION in parent process and d2i_SSL_SESSION/SSL_CTX_add_session in child process) - reference: http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/How-to-share-SSL-sessions-between-parent-and-child-process-when-doing-fork-exec-td11077.html.

I'm looking to other SSL libraries that may allow this, currently looking at NSS.

Is this possible with any mature open source SSL library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few months of trying to find a way to achieve this with libssl, I decided to make my own TLS implementation. I found no way of implementing this functionality without understanding and modifying libssl (or libressl). I still think is possible, I just didn't find a way. I've implemented a TLS library from scratch and put it on [github](https://github.com/eduardsui/tlslayer). Now I have the two needed functions tls_export_context and tls_import_context.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible with any mature open source SSL library?

I don't think it is possible with any SSL library which is implemented in user-space because then you would continuously need to share the state of a single SSL connection among multiple processes. Contrary to this the state of the underlying TCP connection is managed inside the kernel and there is only a single state even if the same connection is open by parent and child process.

And I don't know of any SSL library which is not implemented in user-space.

Comment: That's bad news. I just hoped that is possible to serialize the connection context and transfer it to the child (when transferred, the child is the only one responsible).

Comment: I don' think so. But why don't you simply fork the child only after you've done with the socket in the parent? You only have to watch in this case that you close the socket, but not the SSL part (i.e. no SSL_shutdown) in parent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have the following flow: TCPaccept; SSLinit; SSLread; analyze_header; if (needed) execute_process_to_handle_read_write(...). Can I renegociate the SSL connection in the child process ? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to renegotiate. After fork child has the same state and socket as the parent. As long as you don't do anything with the SSL connection inside the parent you can continue in the child. Thus the best is to close the socket in the parent, which does not close the connection because the child still keeps it open.

Comment: But what if the child process already exists (eg: a worker process) that handles multiple SSL sockets. How do I send a the SSL context to that process? Process A accepts the SSL connection and creates worker B. A accepts another connection, and transfers it to worker B (without forking again). Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You cannot transfer an SSL state between processes. And in your setup you would also need to transfer file descriptors between processes instead of inheriting them during fork. While this is possible (at least on UNIX) it is a very unusual way to work.

Comment: The file descriptors are already shared via sendmsg/SCM_RIGHTS (Unix) and WSADuplicateSocket on Windows. The current setup already works in production, the problem is only with the SSL states. I think that sharing a SSL context should be possible via some kind of serialization (transfer the keys, the states, the vectors and so on). I was hoping that NSS or GnuTLS to support this.