# How to programmatically redirect a program's output to a SSL socket

Tags: linux, sockets, ssl, redirect, openssl

Suppose I have a client-server architecture. The client communicates with the server through a secured SSL TCP connection. Both client and server use `SSL_write` and `SSL_read` for communication.

Then, the server uses `fork` and runs on the child branch 

`close(STDOUT_FILENO)
dup(ssl_socket_from_client)
execvp(...)`

Basically, the output of the program will go into the socket, but will it be encrypted and how do I ensure that anything that goes into this socket uses the same procedure of writing as with `SSL_write`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current state of the SSL socket is in most cases (like with OpenSSL) kept in user space. When forking this state is duplicated into the child. But after the exec this duplicated state is thrown away. This means the executed process has only access to the plain kernel-level file descriptor but not to the SSL state which is needed to transmit encrypted traffic over this file descriptor.

Therefore a simple fork and exec will not work with SSL sockets. Instead the parent process of the executed process needs to handle all the SSL by itself, i.e. read and decrypt data from the SSL socket and provide the executed process with the plain data and read plain data from the executed process and encrypt and forward these data through the SSL socket. Communication with the executed process can for example be done with two pipes or a single socketpair. Or as some rough visualisation:

```
TLS server <--SSL socket--> Parent <--plain socketpair/pipes--> Child
```

For related problems see [Share SSL socket with child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187293/share-ssl-socket-with-child-process) or [Python3 CGI HTTPS server fails on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303343/python3-cgi-https-server-fails-on-unix).

Comment: Okay, so there should be created another socket between the parent and the child. The child will dump it's output into the newly created socket and then the parent will use `SSL_write` to respond.
That makes more sense now, thank you

Comment: Another question:
How do I implement stdin redirection? What if the server runs a command that expects input from the client? With a new level of sockets, I have no idea when to read and when to write to pipes. Are blocking SSL_read and SSL_write even viable in this case?

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii: this is a somehow related but still new question and should thus not be asked in a comment. I recommend to have a look at `pipe` or `socketpair` to create the necessary file descriptors,  use `dup` or `dup2` to map stdin/stdout to these fd in the child and use `select`, `poll`, `kqueue` or whatever you OS offers to find out when data can be read from one fd (ssl or plain) and be forwarded to the other fd (plain or ssl). You could probably also use threads if you are less comfortable with event-driven programming.

Comment: I've implemented the socketpair related stuff, but I didn't know about poll and events on descriptors. Now, when I do, I will progress. Thank you.
Also, I felt like there is too much context inside this question and comments, so starting a new one would be a waste

Comment: I created a separate question following your advice 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084446/linux-socket-input-notification-on-a-client-server-application

Comment: What mechanism causes the duplicated state to be thrown away? If I understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15102328/238704) question the state should be retained in parent and child.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: the state is copied when doing a fork. The user space memory of a process is replaced (and thus implicitly existing state information thrown away) when doing in execv to replace the current process with another one.